# Adopt A Jet/Book

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage

I have a question about the usage of "***adopt***":

> [article 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fighter_aircraft)
>   Grumman's F9F Panther was ***adopted*** by the U.S. Navy as their primary jet fighter in the Korean War period, and it was one of the first jet fighters to employ an afterburner.
>
> [article 2](https://www.kent.edu/success/book-class)
>   Some FYE Instructors and other course instructors ***adopt*** the book for their course for the semester. It is not an expectation of FYE instructors to adopt the book as part of the class.

I checked a [dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/adopt), which has this definition for "adopt":

> def 2a:   to begin to use or have (a different manner, method,  etc.)

which suggests that one can adopt a method, but has no mention of adopting a fighter jet or adopting a book.

So, are the examples wrong?  Could it be that the authors of the articles meant to write "***adapt***" (meaning "modify"), but accidentally used "***adopt***"?

Comment: One can indeed *adopt a method* and the examples are correct. Nice question.

Answer (score 4):

One can indeed *adopt a method* and the examples are correct. In the case of the US Navy's fighter planes, *adopt* means to create an official program for their use, rather than to just buy one or two test aircraft. The case for the course books is the same. The books are *adopted* for general use instead of just having a few copies for evaluation.

In the UK, local councils will *adopt* privately owned roads and assume responsibility for their upkeep. The residents, of course, are charged higher taxes since they no longer have to pay for maintenance. Privately owned roads (for which the public have right of way) have street signs saying "unadopted".

Comment: This is an interesting question: it illustrates the "evolution" of the use of the verb. Even the OED contains no examples of this usage, which might be defined as _to formally approve or ratify sth as fit for a given use or purpose; usually by an organization._ In the U.S. too, local NGO's will _adopt_ a road, often by sending crews to collect litter from the right of way. This applies to an inanimate object the OED's definition 2.f.: _To make (a particular person, animal, etc.) the object of one's charitable concern, esp. as part of an organized campaign; to take up or sponsor (a cause)._

Comment: It sounds like a letter to the editors of the OED might be in order. I shall leave the matter to your good self.

Comment: We'll leave that to brighter lights; I am but a harmless drudge.

Comment: Is a case for course books the same thing as a book-case? I've often wondered. And what about cases for nuts?

Comment: @MickSharpe So, if John bought a new iphone 7, I could write:  "*John* ***adopted*** *the iphone 7*"?

Comment: @P.E.Dant  So the usage of "***adopt***" with fighter jets and books might be considered nonstandard English?

Comment: @meatie If you resolved to buy only iPhone 7's from now on, I suppose that you could, but it would be a little pretentious to make the claim. However if your company decided to replace all their computer kit with Apple products, they could claim to have *adopted* Apple products with some justification.

Comment: @meatie No, not non-standard English; I would call it, instead, _modern_ English. No reader would misunderstand those sentences, and only a very few fusspots would quibble with them. Any living language is always years ahead of its dictionaries. It's also important to remember that the _inclusion_ of some usage examples in a dictionary does not necessarily _exclude_ other usages.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some of the abstract things we can adopt:

```
plan
system
principle
opinion
policy
practice
religion
model
design
```

We've been saying that we have adopted a *design* since the mid 18th century.

When the military adopts a particular fighter jet, they're adopting a **design**. Indeed, the sentence says "it was one of the first jet fighters to employ an afterburner".

When we adopt something, we make it ours, we take it unto ourselves.

Comment: So, if John bought a new iphone 7, I could write:  "*John* ***adopted*** *the iphone 7*"?

Comment: @TRomano  ...but what about OP's second example: _course instructors adopt the book..._? Nothing abstract or conceptual there that I can see. I think the dictionaries have a wee bit of catching up to do here. It's not much of a leap from adopting a design to adopting a physical manifestation of that design, and usage is always ahead of dictionaries—we can't put lexicographers out of work, can we?

Comment: @meatie: A *company* could adopt the iPhone as the mobile phone it issues to its employees, as its "mobile platform", making it "standard issue". In that sense, they're adopting the design or the model. John Q. Public could have been an early-adopter of the iPhone, but I would not say that a person has adopted the iPhone, no.

Comment: @P.E. Dant: A textbook is adopted for an academic course usually because it has been evaluated against certain criteria, analogous to the adoption of a particular fighter jet design by the military. There is an underlying idea of *selection after careful evaluation*.

Comment: I agree that using _adopt_ to describe an individual's purchase (as in OP's comment) is a stretch, but I do think the verb is moving away from the _strictly_ abstract; _course instructors adopt the book_ is a good example. Even the OED doesn't have an example of such a usage. It won't surprise me to see _9. to formally approve or ratify sth as fit for a given use or purpose; usually by an organization_ in a future edition, with no mention of evaluation against criteria. It's an interesting question. I'll bet we could find other examples of such "drift" if we looked for them.

Comment: @P.E.Dant: Course instructors adopt *textbooks*, not books, right? We wouldn't say "She has adopted Heller's *Catch 22* for the course", would we?   What is common to the textbook and the fighter jet design, and what is lacking from a specific novel or a particular iPhone, is what licenses the use of **adopt** with the former pair but not the latter. I think the word will have to drift on the tides for quite a while longer before we hear "I just adopted the latest iPhone.".

Comment: @TRomano _Today,_ absolutely, Bob doesn't _adopt_ an iPhone. We aren't there yet. But the Kent State usage (the entirety of which is very weird, by the way) is already yanking at the cleat on the dock, and what with _adopting_ even [_cars,_](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&hl=en-gb&ei=pjXxV8fIE4WBmQGGnL2IBA&q=adopt+a+car) the waters are rough.